Shopify app proxy returns 302 status code and redirect /auth/login
I have a shopify app proxy so that I can get data from my db and populate it in the app theme extension.  Below is my liquid  file and proxy file. Everything works good, the console.log is printed when I call the function but in the frontend I keep getting  the below response:
Request URL: https://kitapp-testapp.myshopify.com/apps/badge
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 302 Found
Remote Address: [2620:127:f00f:e::]:443
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
location: /auth/login


Below are the liquid file and proxy file:



